# new connection.confirmTransaction function with BlockheightBasedTransactionConfirmationStrategy not an option

Tags: web3.js

I'm trying to use the new function with Argument of type 'BlockheightBasedTransactionConfirmationStrategy' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

But I can't see it in version "@solana/web3.js": "^1.63.1",

Is it in a dev version or something?

Answer (score 1):

This strategy was added to `confirmTransaction` in v1.41.11 of `@solana/web3.js`.